# Is wearing loose trousers haram?

Tags: clothing, awrah

I wear loose trousers and loose jeans with loose shirt or loose t shirt which is knee length. My dress up doesn’t show my exact figure.I also wear hoodie or short t shirt with long skirt with knee length socks. So literally i cover my body and no one can tell my body shape. Since i have heard comment about my dress up i want to ask is my dress up halal or haram?

Answer (score -1):

I have seen that in different Islamic cultures and countries, the limits of hijab are observed completely differently. Some only cover their hair and wear tight clothes, and some hide completely in tents and masks. Some people are satisfied with the minimum hijab and some want the highest and most complete hijab. The principle of hijab is so that a woman does not show off in front of non-mahrams with her feminine beauty.
You emphasize that your clothes are loose or your skirt is long. You can control yourself better than any other person to what extent your clothes have Islamic limits ?!? Some clothes get wet with sweat in summer and the underwear is marked. Some clothes are so tight that they completely reveal the lines of the underwear and the size of the body. Well, it is clear that they do not have an Islamic hijab.

Sometimes think of your friends' advice. That is, if someone's right is lost or someone's reputation is lost, or if someone or a group has deviated from the right path because of his propaganda, he should Let them know.Maybe they noticed something in your cover that you did not notice.